# 5hp submersible pump, dual purpose: irrigation and home use

Tags: pump, well

I just had a new 4" open well drilled (Florida) with 5hp submersible pump. The primary use of the well is irrigating 1.5ac property. I also want to use the same well and pump as a backup for our home which is about 150ft away from the new well.

Current home supply well and pressure tank, and house main shutoff valve are located on the opposite side of the house. How would you go about plumbing the above with another pressure tank, check valve(s), and combining irrigation system with the home supply after the new pump and controller.

Comment: Open, as in "not capped" is not a suitable well for human use, since things fall into such wells and contaminate them. OK for irrigation, has negative impacts up to and including death for drinking.

Comment: Yeah -- drinking wells need to be maintained to potable water standards, with a full cap and pitless adapter takeoff as well as sanitization of the well equipment and a proper grouting/cement job on the annulus to prevent the wellbore from being a highway for contaminants

Comment: I missed to say, we have full filtration system after our old well. Well water around here is full of iron and other contaminants but after filtration it tastes like spring water. With said fact I would likely need to run potable water line from new well all the way 150ft to the house one side and probably another 200ft to the filtration system on the opposite side of house. Old well is shallow with jet pump, new well is as deep as it gets down here in SE FL at around 190ft, so water from it must be much higher quality. Well is capped, by open I meant submersible pump is fitted in its casing

Comment: We dont use potable water from old nor will we use water directly from the new well. Filtration system consists 20mic sediment pre-filter, iron/ sulfur filter, carbon filter, 5mic sediment filter, salt water softener, UV, then it goes to house for non drinking use. Separately we have RO system for consumption and drinking. Where would a pressure switch be installed if you are feeding water to pressure tank and irrigation, I suppose pressure tank would be near house filtration system which would be over 350-400ft away from the pump